# Bound of sums of cotninuous functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $x_n(t)$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ by $x_n(t)=nt$ for $ t \in [0,1/n]$, $x_n(t)=2-nt$ for $t \in [1/n,2/n]$ and $x_n(t)=0$ for $t \in [2/n,1]$.

Here $n$ is any natural number.

Let a sequence $\{ n_k\}$ of natural numbers be such that $n_{k+1} > 2n_k$.
 Then for any natural number $K$ and $t \in [0,1]$, I have to show that $y_K(t)=\sum_1^Kx_{n_k}(t) < 4$

I tried to prove by drawing pictures but cannot find an approrpriate bound for $y_K$. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Note that the $n_k$'s are chosen so that $$\frac{2}{n_{k+1}} < \frac{1}{n_k},$$ i.e. so the peak of $x_{n_{k}}(t)$ avoids the domain of $x_{n_{k+1}}(t)$.  It may also be helpful to iterate $t< \frac{1}{n_k} < \frac{1}{2n_{k-1}} < \frac{1}{2^2n_{k-2}} < \dots.$

Answer (score 0):

Below is a partial answer:

First since $y_k(t)=\sum_{1}^K x_{n_k}(t)$, and each $x_{n_k}(t)$ is a piecewise function, I think a good starting point is to begin with evaluating the sum on the interval $[0,\frac{1}{n_K}]$. On this interval each $x_{n_k}(t)=n_kt$ and hence $y_K(t)= \left(\sum_{1}^K n_k\right)t$. The maximum value obviously occurs at right endpoint and hence $y_K(\frac{1}{n_K})$ is the maximum value. I will assume first that $n_{k+1} = 2 n_k $. With this condition $y_K(\frac{1}{n_K})=\left(\sum_{1}^K n_12^{k-1}\right)\frac{1}{n_1 2^{K-1}}$. The sum can be evaluated explicitly as $n_1\left(2^{K}-1\right)$ and thus $y_K(\frac{1}{n_K})=\frac{2^K-1}{2^{K-1}}$. As K tends to infinity $y_K(\frac{1}{n_K})$ tends to 2, which is less than the bound 4.

Clearly the above only applies to the interval $[0,\frac{1}{n_K}]$, but some investigation will show that $y_K(t)$ decreases after $t=\frac{1}{n_K}$. Also, the above only considered a particular geometric series for $n_{K+1}$.